# Nester Module not working in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and I have been trying to run this code from Head First Python.
I am currently running on Python 2.7.9

Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import nester

man = []
other = []

try:
    data = open('sketch.txt')

    for each_line in data:
            try:
                    (role, line_spoken) = each_line.split(':' , 1)
                    line_spoken = line_spoken.strip()
                    if role == 'Man':
                        man.append(line_spoken)
                    elif role == 'Other Man':
                        other.append(line_spoken)

            except ValueError:
                    pass

    data.close()

except IOError:
        print('the data file is missing')

try:
        with open('man_data.txt', 'w') as man_file:
                print_lol(man, file = man_file)
        with open('other_data.txt', 'w') as other_file:
                print_lol(other, file = other_file)

        man_file.close()
        other_file.close()

except IOError as err:
        print('File error: ' + str(err))
```

and here is the nester code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
def print_lol(the_list, indent=False, level=0, fh=sys.stdout):


 for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            print_lol(each_item , indent, level+1, fh)

        else:
            if indent:
                    for tab_stop in range(level):
                        print("\t", end='', file=fh)


            print(each_item, file=fh)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Olusegun\Desktop\Python codes\HeadFirstPython\Chapter 3\data.py", line 30, in <module>
    print_lol(man, file = man_file)
NameError: name 'print_lol' is not defined
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: it would be nice if you formatted your post better ... add an extra 4 spaces at the beginning of every line that has code in it

Comment: Before you get too far into learning, *please* switch to Python 3. Python 2 is the past, Py3 is the present and future of the language. Unless you have a very specific reason for learning 2 first, use 3. You can always pick up the differences later. Py2 can teach you some bad habits that will impede your progress in 3. HFP also uses Py3, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print_lol` is in `nester` module and you just `import nester`, you should call `print_lol` with `nester.print_lol()`

Or you can `from nester import print_lol`, such that you can call `print_lol`.

You should know how to [import Python modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)

> Python provides at least three different ways to import modules. You can use the import statement, the from statement, or the builtin **import** function. (There are more contrived ways to do this too, but that’s outside the scope for this small note.)
>
> Anyway, here’s how these statements and functions work:
>
> - **import X** imports the module X, and creates a reference to that module in the current namespace. Or in other words, after you’ve run this statement, you can use X.name to refer to things defined in module X.
> - **from X import *** imports the module X, and creates references in the current namespace to all public objects defined by that module (that is, everything that doesn’t have a name starting with “_”). Or in other words, after you’ve run this statement, you can simply use a plain name to refer to things defined in module X. But X itself is not defined, so X.name doesn’t work. And if name was already defined, it is replaced by the new version. And if name in X is changed to point to some other object, your module won’t notice.
> - **from X import a, b, c** imports the module X, and creates references in the current namespace to the given objects. Or in other words, you can now use a and b and c in your program.
> - Finally, **X = __import__(‘X’)** works like import X, with the difference that you 1) pass the module name as a string, and 2) explicitly assign it to a variable in your current namespace.

Comment: @Chidexebere, if my answer is helpful, please accept my answer